# No module named - jupyter notebook WSL2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this folders structure:

```
-project
--utils
---helpers.py
--code
---code_subfolder
----notebook.ipynb
```

If I use a local python interpreter I have no problem to import helpers.py from notebook.ipynb with

`from utils.helpers import *`

But if I switch to a python interpreter inside a WSL subsystem with Ubuntu the same line of code will result in the error

> no module named 'utils'

How can i fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the `project` folder to your PYTHONPATH env var.

Comment: I managed to make it work by adding inside .vscode/settings.json the line `"jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"`